# What is happening in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am trying to understand how this script is doing what it does.

```
  object.variable = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (variable = functor(_), object) : variable;
  };
```

It is clearly used to allow the overriding of a default `variable` value on `object`, but what would be wrong with this code:

```
  object.variable = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? variable = _ : variable;
  };
```

Having found the functor function:

```
function functor(d) {
  return typeof d === "function" ? d : function() { return d; };
}
```

I can see that this ensures that whatever is passed in is treated as a function.

So why this construct in Javascript, `(variable = functor(_), object)`, I don't understand how this works? Why not just `variable = functor(_)`

Comment: What is your `functor` function?

Comment: The first code [returns the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), the second does not.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  ok, that was useful, for some reason I was assuming this was a native thing, but there was also a functor function, will edit the question

Comment: Where and how is `variable` declared? Notice that the identifier inside the function does not refer to the `.variable` property on your `object`.

Comment: where do you have the code from?

Comment: @Bergi Ah, yes, that's right, `variable` is defined globally within the `exports function` _alongside_ `object`, so what does that mean in this context?

Comment: next time just write us all the global defined variables which are included the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why this construct in Javascript, `(variable = functor(_), object)`, I don't understand how this works? Why not just `variable = functor(_)`

The author of this approach basically is using [`comma-operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in order to call `functor(...)` and finally return `object`.

The [`comma-operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) executes expressions separated by a comma, so the latest expression will be the result of its execution.

*Take a look at this:*

```js
let result = (1,2,3,4,5 === 5);
console.log(result); // Here will be printed true because 5 === 5 was the last expression.
```

Comment: Thankyou, `comma-operator` was the link I was looking for.  Funny how Google is only useful when you already know what it is you are looking for (good job there is StackOverflow for the rest!), I'll accept when the time limit allows me.

Comment: Did you mean to use `(1,2,3,4,5) === 5`? Otherwise I can't make sense of the `=== 5` part.

Comment: @Bergi I just wanted to illustrate how the last expression is assigned to the variable result.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the difference is in returning the object:

```
object.variable = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (variable = functor(_), object) : variable;
};
```

can be written like this:

```
object.variable = function(_) {

    if (arguments.length) {
        variable = functor(_);
        return object;
    } else {
        return variable;
    }
};
```

Whereas

```
object.variable = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? variable = _ : variable;
};
```

can be written like this:

```
object.variable = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        variable = _;
    } else {
        return variable;
    }
};
```

Comment: The last snippet should have `return variable` under `variable = _` in the if block

Answer (score 0):

`var variable = (f(1), f(2));`

results in `f(1)` and `f(2)` being executed in order (as mentioned above, [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)), with `variable` being assigned the value of `f(2)`. Therefore, the first example will, if an argument is provided, assign `functor(_)` to `variable` and return `object`. If there is no argument, nothing will happen and `variable` will be returned.

It is extremely important to point out that this code is riddled with anti-patterns, and unless it is a part of some school task it should be refactored as it is confusing. For example:

- You should never assign and return a value in the same expression
- You shouldn't call a function `functor` unless `functor` is a proper name (function names should be descriptive)
- You shouldn't check for `arguments` unless absolutely necessary  - considering you actually pass a named argument, why not just test for `!!_`?
- Unless using `lodash` or `underscore`, why are you naming an argument `_`? What does it even mean, what does it represent?
- You should avoid `(1, 2)` notation unless absolutely necessary, it makes the code unnecessarily difficult to follow. Use `if` instead, what is the benefit of doing all these things in one line of code?